# Difficult to filtrate the user Dimension table

Tags: ssas, mdx

I have dimension table, named user, and fact table. I want to filtrate that right user can review right value from the fact table based on user's windows authenication. You use the WA to filtrate the dimension table.

I have used the syntax code `"{STRTOMEMBER("[xxxxx].[xxxxxx].&[" + Username() + "]")}"` at the textbox "Allowed member set". (Picture 1).

Unfortunately, the value in fact table is not working.

Do you guys have a better solution?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

THe context do not work. you have follow guideline below exactly unfortunately.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NlNw3wYbh8E

http://bifuture.blogspot.se/2011/09/ssas-setup-dynamic-security-in-analysis.html

http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1834/introduction-to-dimension-security-in-sql-server-analysis-services-ssas-2005/

http://www.rodcolledge.com/rod_colledge/2010/10/ssas-dynamic-security-kerberos-and-performancepoint.html